# flex 4: IFocusManager.moveFocus() api has been removed, any alternative way

Tags: flex4, focusmanager

I am working on migrating our app to compile with Flex 4 framework libraries. One of the things I bumped into yesterday was the IFocusManager.moveFocus() api which was previously there in Flex 3, seems to have been removed from Flex 4. We make use of this api in a bunch of places in our code.

So, I was wondering if anyone else has bumped into this problem and if there is a known alternative to this in Flex 4. I cannot find any documentation around this. Seems a bit strange that apis are removed without any alternative documented in the code or without first deprecating them, to give sufficient time for developers to seek and test alternatives.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a method calles setFocus(). Maybe you can use this to replace the moveFocus().